# MVC5 delayed event

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

**General question**

From my backend code I want to trigger events that will wait somewhere around 30 minutes and then run a bit of code.

Given that its a bad idea to spawn threads or tasks in MVC (as the pool can be killed and you don't really know if things are going to work or not). What is the best way to do this?

My options as I see them are:

- Create a thread or task from the code.. *bad idea as mentioned above.*
- Create a scheduled task (batch/powershell) on the server that calls a service every 30 minutes
  that does the emailing as needed. *This to me is messy as I now depend on this task working*
- Create an SSIS package on the SQL server to do pretty much the same as the scheduled task, but perhaps more reliably. *Probably the most dependable solution, but also the most pain in the ### one.*.

What would you guys do?

**Real world example**

User "A" writes a comment on the website. User "B" and "C" both comment this post within 5 minutes of each other. I want to send an email to User "A" about the new comments from "B" and "C", but I don't want him to get 1 email for every commment.. There could be hundreds and noone wants 100 emails about 1 comment each.

So in my case I want to trigger an even that waits 30 minutes and then groups all new comments into one notification email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no correct answer to this question, it is primarily opinion-based.

Personally I like #2, it doesn't seem messy to me. You could do something like a WorkerRole or WebJob. Cloud computing is as much about timed events as web requests (ok maybe not as much, but it still plays a meaningful role in many applications).

I also like #2 because it seems more unit testable to me, but maybe that's because I don't know how to write unit tests against an SSIS package.

Answer (score 0):

Web server is not the right tool to for scheduled tasks. The server goes into sleep after a period of time if there is no request coming. I know there are some hacks you can do to make it work..but hacks are hacks, I always prefer to do thing the right way. To do so you would want to write some c# application and use windows service to accomplish the job, or SQL Server agent.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there's also another option. You could expose some app on the server which has web interface so you can enqueue some task. Then internal logic of that app could send your e-mails or do anything you want. It won't be the MVC web application but some service, so it won't be at risk to be killed by application pool recycling or anything else.